# Volley cache update strategy

Tags: android, caching

I'm using volley as news application network library. I want my application in first connection, fetch all available news in webservice, then every time I open my application , if the new news is available on server update volley cache. the question is what is the usual way to update cache? Is sending notification from server good strategy or checking the server every time application open?

Comment: Well if it's possible in your case then sending notification from server is obviously better since user could open application 100 times in a row and each time you would need to send request to check if new news are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 main options:
 1. use purely default http cache (default volley implementation or the one of any hhtp stack that volley uses)
 2. use your own custom cache where you can define exactly how and what to cache

I'll go in detail for option 1. as it seems you use this one.

When you have cached responses normally you don't need external info when to update those as the info is contained in the returned cache headers.

So the response (an article for example) can be:
1) cached with valid cache - in which case no request go to the Network layer
2) cached witch needs to be re-validated - in which case you may receive new version of the response or 304 response with NO body which means current cache is valid and can be still used
3) not cached - in which case a new request is made

Which means that if you have correct cache headers for your news server you can make requests any time the app starts or the activity resumes in order to check for new data and you don't need to worry that too many requests will be send. Especially if your article change frequency is high this is better option.

On the other hand if you don't have proper headers or you update your news rarely then it is an option to send push notifications however u need to send those to all your clients so its not feasible to do it when u have many changes and also the complexity of the implementation, maintenance and costs will be higher.